# Перебор простых чисел

Tags: python, алгоритм, простые-числа

Нужен алгоритм который будет перебирать простые числа, чтобы я их в этом цикле мог использовать. Нужно перебирать простые числа с самого маленького и затем производить с числом действия, если число не подошло идти к следующему если подошло то выход из цикла. Именно поэтому алгоритм который находит простые числа в определенном промежутке не подходит так как нету точного конечного числа

Comment: Перебирайте подряд и проверяйте. Науке пока неизвестен способ перехода от i-го простого числа к i+1-му... А проверить, простое число или нет - тут уже рассматривалось, наверное, сотни раз... Да, можете немного ускорить перебор, заведомо не проверяя четные (т.е.начиная с 3, увеличивать число на 2).

Comment: Проблема в том, что такой метод будет очень неэффективным, у него сложность `O(n)` для каждого очередного числа, а `n` растёт при этом. Методы нахождения простых чисел сразу массово должны работать быстрее, по идее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import math
def prime_num():
    nm = 2
    while True:
        sq = math.ceil(nm ** 1 / 2)
        for i in range(2, sq + 1):
            if (nm % i) == 0:
                break
        else:
            yield nm
        nm += 1

for i in prime_num(): # Бесконечно генерирует простые числа начиная с 2
    # do smth with i
    ...
```

Также можно использовать алгоритм решета Эратосфена если нужны простые числа до определённого числа

```
from functools import reduce

n = 100 # Простые числа до 100

primes = reduce(lambda r, x: r - set(range(x**2, n, x)) if x in r else r, range(2, int(n**0.5) + 1), set(range(2, n)))

print(primes)
# {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97}
```

Comment: `nm ** 1 / 2` -> `(nm ** 1) / 2` -> `nm / 2`. На правильность не влияет, только на скорость.

Answer (score 2):

как вариант, можно использовать библиотеки, например gmpy2, примерно так:

> next_prime(x) returns the next probable prime number > x

```
import gmpy2

p = 1  # простое число
while True:
    # ваши действия с числом
    if  # условие выхода из цикла
        break
    p = gmpy2.next_prime(p)
```